# How to handle Alamofire responses and reuse in different Views

Tags: json, xcode, alamofire

I am newbie in Xcode, sorry if is a basic question need to use the first response in static view and the second in tableview, maybe is some common way to handle both and read data from other view, I can make both responses return the same keys, or if is better push the first in "hits".
Thanks in advance.

I make the requests with Alamofire with .responseJSON
One returning simple row with the following response:

```
 success({
    adultos = 2;
    aeropuerto = "<null>";
    bebes = 0;
    compania = "<null>";
    destino = Aeropuerto;
    dia = 0;
    direccion = "calle aragon";
    enapto = 0;
    entaxi = 0;
    exito = 1;
    fecha = "0000-00-00";
    finalizado = 0;
})

Other with variable number of rows returning

success({
    hits =  (
        {
            destino = "Son Servera";
            dia = 24;
            direccion = "Torre Marina, Ronda de Sol Ixent, 22";
            entaxi = 1;
            fecha = "2021-06-24";
            hora = "22:20";
            "id_reservas" = 958687;
            mes = "Thursday June 2021";
            "nombre_cliente" = "SERVICIO DE PRUEBA";
            origen = Aeropuerto;
        },
        {
            destino = "AIDA Cruceros";
            dia = 25;
            direccion = prueba;
            entaxi = 1;
            fecha = "2021-06-25";
            hora = "12:00";
            "id_reservas" = 959442;
            mes = "Friday June 2021";
            "nombre_cliente" = "TONI CARDONA";
            origen = Aeropuerto;
        },        
    );
})
```

Comment: hello @Toni Cardona this is some of the basic concept which you need to understand , I would request you to search for  "encodable/decodable data parsing swift" to understand how to process the json data in structured manner. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Have found with your suggestion and struct decodable works fine